# Matrix representing bilinear form on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

Suppose $Q$ is a quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $$Q(x,y,z)=xy + 2xz -2y^2-2z^2$$

I want to find the matrix representing the bilinear form associated with this quadratic form in the standard basis. To do this I have written the quadratic form in the following way: $$Q(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix} x & y & z\end{pmatrix}   \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 1 \\ \frac{1}{2} & -2 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & -2\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Perfectly correct.

Comment: Well... *perfectly* correct it is not since in your last line, on the right side, the first vector **must be** a row one and not a column one, as then the product isn't defined...But for this little thing it all is alright.

Comment: @DonAntonio It's defensible since the first column is dotted with the matrix-vector product on the right, and dot product is between two column vectors. However, in that interpretation you get into associativity problems. At any rate we're picking nits.

Comment: @Arthur Good point there, indeed.+1

Comment: The matrix is always half the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives.

Comment: @DonAntonio I've made an edit to my post. Is it correct now?